# how to save data to different table of sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am new in sqlite in ios. Thus, what I have to do first and next in order to save data to different tables of database?

Comment: Since CoreData is available in iOS since 3.0 sdk and is very helpful in applications, so it would be great, if you can start with CoreData

Comment: first u have to store data in database then in array. when u get data in array then you can simply show data in tableview

Comment: I have read about coredata already, but it seems difficult than sqlite, so i choose to use sqlite first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Sqlite database in my various application, it works fine for me. You have to follow these steps for inserting the data in the tables of Sqlite database ...

1.First of all you need to create your database... I hope you have created and inserted in your project and also added linked framework libsqlite3.0.dylib and import these in your classes. 
2. Replace your insertion method write this code ...

```
+(void)insertRecord:(NSString *)dbPath record:(NSMutableArray*)dataArray{
    @try{
        sqlite3_stmt *insertStmnt;
        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

            for(int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++){
                id record=[dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Table_Name (\"Column1\",\"Column2\",\"Column3\",\"Column4\",) VALUES('%@','%@','%@','%@')",[[record objectForKey:@"col1"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"],[[record objectForKey:@"col2"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"],[[record objectForKey:@"col3"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"],[[record objectForKey:@"col4"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"]];

                const char *sql = [insertQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insertStmnt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

                }else{

                }
                if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmnt)){

                }


            }
        }
    }@catch (NSException *r) {
        NSLog(@"UU %@",r);
    } 
}
```

Where record is the array of dictionary, which contains the values which you want to insert in the table or values get from the user.
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
The above method is necessary because if any user enters the data with single cote, then it will lead to your application crash.(you may remove this if you does not take input from the user)

Yes, You can also follow these links for better understanding..
1.http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Database_Implementation_using_SQLite
2.SQLite Tutorial

Hope it will work for you, if you have any query then may reply..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQLite then go get [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as it will make your life alot easier. All that code above can be shrunk down to a thread safe call something like (off the top of my head, so probably not compile ready).

```
[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        [db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (f1,f2) VALUES (%@, %@);", field1, field2];

        DLog(@"insert error: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }];
```